# Keyboard doesn't disappear when sliding back to question from answer(s)

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

To replicate:

1. Open any question in the app with one or more answers
2. Start topping a comment on the answer
3. Slice your finger towards the right over the answer to return to the question

Note that the keyboard remains on the screen, and when you slide back to the answer(s), the keyboard is not activated.

Comment: Works both ways, from question or answers, and it doesn't matter if you tap the tabs or slide. In fact, the keyboard will not disappear unless you either call it again or submit the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version 0.1.51 coming out later tonight the app will automatically hide the on screen keyboard when toggling between questions and answers (either by swiping or hitting the tabs), and it'll also keep track of your comment so you can resume right back up when you toggle back.